# Dice rolls stats on Python

Tags: python, function, statistics, package, dice

I am having some trubles trying to figure out how this function works:

```
import control

 def sevenStats(numRolls):
     sevenCount=0
     for i in range (numRolls):
         roll = control.rollDie(6) + control.rollDie(6)
         if roll == 7
             sevenCount += 1
      return sevenCount
```

In particular I didn't catch what this line does:

```
 roll = control.rollDie(6) + control.rollDie(6)
```

The purpose of the overall function should be to keep track of a given number's rolls, in this case the number = 7.

Can you help me go trough this ? Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I guess that the function control.rollDie(num) generates a random number between 1 and the indicate number, in this case 6. It roll two dices thats why it add it 2 times. Ans then it counts how many times the sum (roll) is equal to 7.

Answer (score 0):

The function is counting the times you obtain a 7 when throwing two dices in n tries.

```
roll = control.rollDie(6) + control.rollDie(6)
```

That line of code sums the values of the two dices you have throw.

Answer (score 0):

`control.rollDie(6)` generates a random number between 1 and the value given in the parameter which in this case is 6.

```
roll = control.rollDie(6) + control.rollDie(6)
```

So what this line does is that it generates two random numbers between 1 and 6 and then adds them together and stores the value in the variable `roll`